# Regular expression to validate chars by comma

Tags: c#, regex

It should validate something like this:

```
a,b,c,d,1,2,3,w,f,x,-,=,d
```

Accepted only one char and next is comma.

*Bad example:*

```
adc,1,2,345,flos
```

I tried using this c# pattern but it doesn't work.

```
@"([*{1}]+[,{1}])+"
```

Comment: please elaborate little bit more

Comment: so one char and comma after?

Comment: Does it *have* to be a RegEx? If not, I find this a lot clearer than any RegEx: `myString.Split(',').Any(x => x.Length > 1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `^[^,](,[^,])*$`. The structure is as follows:

1. a single non comma character: `[^,]`
2. arbitrary many times a comma followed by a non comma character: `(,[^,])*`

If you want to match an empty string as well you should make the whole expression optional:

`^([^,](,[^,])*)?$`

Answer (score 0):

If you want find any group from allowed `char with comma`, the easises way would be this

```
(a|b|c|d|1|2|3|w|f|x|\-|\=)\,
```

Answer (score 0):

It gives you what you want i guess :

```
bool isMatched = IsValid("adc,1,2,345,flos");   

    private bool IsValid(string value)
    {
            return Regex.IsMatch(value, @"^([^,](,[^,])*)?$");
    }
```